# Apply function with arguments to a dataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to apply a function to a dataframe, where the arguments come from the dataframe itself. Is there a way to do this succinctly?

```
df: 
    | a  | b  | c  | d |
A   | 20 | 15 | 33 | 5 |
B   | 5  | 6  | 10 | 8 |
C   | 10 | 15 | 5  | 10|
```

Function to apply to each cell

```
# c = sum of the current column
# r = sum of the current row 
# t = sum of all values
def calcIndex(x, c, r, t):
    return (x/c)*(t/r)*100
```

Result

```
    | a   | b   | c   | d   |
A   | 111 | 81  | 134 | 42  |
B   | 70  | 82  | 102 | 170 |
C   | 101 | 148 | 37  | 154 |
```

I've tried `df.apply` but not sure how to access the specific row/column total depending on which `x` is being calculated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) here is possible loop by columns or by index, not by both, so cannot be used here, if need both in one function.

Better and faster is use vectorized functions with [`DataFrame.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html), [`DataFrame.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) and [`DataFrame.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html), last use [`DataFrame.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html) with [`DataFrame.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) for integers in output:

```
c = df.sum(axis=1)
r = df.sum()
t = r.sum()
df1 = df.div(c, axis=0).mul(t).div(r).mul(100).round().astype(int)
print (df1)
     a    b    c    d
A  111   81  134   42
B   70   82  102  170
C  101  148   37  154
```

For improve performance is possible use `numpy`:

```
#pandas 0.24+
arr = df.to_numpy()
#pandas below
#arr = df.values
c = arr.sum(axis=1)
r = arr.sum(axis=0)
t = r.sum()
out = np.round(arr / c[:, None] * t / r * 100).astype(int)
df = pd.DataFrame(out, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
print (df)
     a    b    c    d
A  111   81  134   42
B   70   82  102  170
C  101  148   37  154
```

Answer (score 1):

This was a bit tricky question.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'a':[20, 5, 10], 'b':[15, 6, 15], 'c':[33, 10, 5], 'd':[5, 8, 10]}, index=['A', 'B', 'C'])

total = data.values.sum() # total sum

data['row_sum'] = data.sum(axis=1) # create a new column 'row_sum' containing sum of elements in that row
col_sum = data.sum(axis=0) # column sum

data = data.loc[:,'a':'d'].div(data['row_sum'], axis=0) # divide each cell with its row sum
data.loc['col_sum'] = col_sum # create a new row with corresponding column sum
data = data.loc['A':'C',:].div(data.loc['col_sum'], axis=1) # divide each cell with its column sum

def update(x):
    return int(round(x*total*100)) # round number to nearest integer       

data_new = data.applymap(update)
```

output:

```
     a    b    c    d
A  111   81  134   42
B   70   82  102  170
C  101  148   37  154
```